# Censoring text with php and regex

Tags: php, regex

using PHP what would the regex be for replacing all alpha numeric characters (and all punctuation except for dot) with ascii bullet code (• • •   Bullet). Say the input string was simply:

```
$str = "some text $12,345."
```

which would output as
•••• •••• •••••••.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? This is pretty simple to achieve with a minimal amount of research..

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in solving the actual problem, including the attempted code and the encountered issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `preg_replace`:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/[^\s.]/', '•', $str);
```

Comment: Should be `•` instead of `*`

Comment: Thanks @ShankarDamodaran: My tired eyes couldn't see it. It is updated now.